# How to organize frontend infrastructure with dockerized MERN

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can you please tell me, how do I organize my frontend infrastructure for MERN stack dockerized app?

For example, I will need a container for MongoDB, Node separately, organized with docker-compose, right? so what and how should I do with react then? do I deploy it in separate docker and bundle with previous MongoDB and Node with docker-compose, or should I deploy it on the frontend server(Nginx as reverse proxy)? Where should I install the SSL, if indeed frontend suppose to be in docker?

I mean you clearly can tell I'm very newbie in this topic and generally in all of the devops, so please tell whatever is in you mind(regards this topic :) ), it might help me out!

Thanks